# How do I create an Event Template?

Tags: civievent

How do I create an event template?

I've selected *Event Templates > Add Event Template*

Filled out the details and saved the event. I got a new event instead of an event template. The Event Templates screen still reports that I have no templates present.

[image: There are no event templates present]

Versions: CiviCRM 5.44.0 and drupal 9.2.10

Comment: Do you want to try at https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/eventTemplate?reset=1. I just went through and it created  new one for me. watch your urls, in case something twitches on your site

Comment: Could you add civi version?

Comment: civicrm/event/add?action=add&is_template=1&reset=1 - URL looks the same.

Comment: Just tested on d9 Civi 5.44, was able to create one